# ng-init or equivalent on partial view load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm calling a partial view from my angular controller with a GET from the server. I'm calling `$compile` on this partial because I'm binding some data to it. However, I need one of my scope variables (an object) to get some data from the server once the partial is loaded.

I tried to add an `ng-init='getDataForObject()` but this doesnt seem to be working. Is there an alternative way of doing this? or is there a way to call a function once the partial view is loaded.

correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like this partial view is getting its own instance of the controller, is this true? because I tried to get the object data from inside the GET on the inital call to get the partial, but that didnt work, which must mean that the object isnt the same one as in the partial

Comment: Did my answer below help resolve this issue?

Comment: @CarsonDrake sorry I haven't done anything with it yet, I'm starting to work on it now. I'll update once I figure it out or have more questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a general view object and then assigning a sub object. to handle the subview you are referring to? Single level object changes don't propagate to parent scopes in most cases, but multi-level object changes do propagate upward.